# How to insert a record using Eloquent (Laravel) relationships?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables: `UserActivities` and `Activities`.

Activities:

```
| Column | Type             |
|--------|------------------|
| id     | int              |
| name   | varchar(255)     |
|        |                  |
```

UserActivities:

```
| Column      | Type | Comment                  |
|-------------|------|--------------------------|
| id          | int  |                          |
| user_id     | int  |                          |
| activity_id | int  | //id of activity by name |
```

Now to insert an item Item into `UserActivity` Model I have to write two statements like this

```
$activity = Activity::where('name', '=', 'user_login')->first();
UserActivity::create(['user_id' => Auth::login(), 'activity_id' => $activity->id]);
```

While this is fine, but I was just reading up on [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) and wondering if there was a way to create `belongsTo` or some relationship and insert it directly like this

```
UserActivity::create(['user_id' => Auth::login(), 'activity' => 'user_login']);
```

And it automatically inserts `activity_id` by searching the name? Is it possible?

Comment: Like https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models ?

Comment: No it's not possible, you need to find the activity ID before you insert the activity. If you know it you can do `\Auth::user()->userActivities()->save(new UserActivity(["activity_id" => $id ])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more research after reading @kerbholz comment, I think this is the way to do it?

Activity.php (Model)

```
class Activity extends Model {
    public function user_activities() {
        return $this->hasMany(UserActivity::class);
    }
}
```

Main code:

```
Activity::where('name', '=', 'user_login')->first()->user_activities()
    ->create(['user_id' => Auth::id()]);
```

Or in my case, this makes sure the Activity name always exists:

```
Activity::updateOrCreate(['name' => 'user_test'])->user_activities()->create(['user_id' => 1]);
```